# MonoTouch.Dialog: how to use fancy GlassButton?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm wondering what is the best use of Miguel's `GlassButton` class in combination with MonoTouch.Dialog? Is there some built in mechanism that would turn a StringElement with attached tap handler into a `GlassButton`?
Or am I supposed to make custom view elements that inherit/contain the GlassButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any UIViews to MonoTouch.Dialog by wrapping UIViews in the UIViewElement, like this:

```
 var myWrapper = new UIViewElement (new GlassButton (rect));

 section.Add (myWrapper);
```

Comment: What would "rect" be if I want to match the size of the default elements? I don't want to hardcode it.